# Access User.Identity.Name in HTMLHelper class

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am writing an HTMLHelper but I need to access User.Identity.Name, how do I do that?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
public static string YourHtmlHelper(this HtmlHelper html)
{
    var name = html.ViewContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

you might want to check and see if User.Identity is null first before trying to grab the Name.

```
    public static string YourHtmlHelper(this HtmlHelper html) 
    { 
        var identity = html.ViewContext.HttpContext.User.Identity;

        if (identity != null)
        {
            return html.ViewContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
        }

        return string.Empty;
    }
```